# wkhtmltopdf wkhtmltoimage: cannot connect to X server

Tags: xorg, 10.04, source-code, wkhtmltopdf

I compiled wkhtmltopdf from source on Ubuntu 64bit server 10.04 as described in manual. When I try to convert it exits with an error message:

```
wkhtmltoimage: cannot connect to X server
```

There is X server installed but not running.
If I download already built version it is working but sometimes throws "Segmentation fault" exception.

So how to make compiled from source version work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to install xvfb (Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server):

```
apt-get install xvfb
```

Then in the terminal:

```
xvfb-run wkhtmltoimage --format png --quality 100 --no-debug-javascript --height 800 http://facebook.com/ fb.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the above issue in  Ubuntu 18.04

Solved the issue by upgrading the wkhtmltoimage to 0.12.5.1

1. Download the dep/rpm/exe format from the Github release page [link here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/tag/0.12.5)
2. In ubuntu

   `wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb`

   `sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb`

(link need to replace with your matching version in GitHub release page