# paraview: cannot connect to X server

Tags: xserver

I just installed paraview from Ubuntu repository using:

`sudo apt install paraview`

But I get the error below when I try to run it typing `paraview` in the command line.

`paraview: cannot connect to X server`

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Take a look at this to see if it can solve your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/64820/wkhtmltopdf-wkhtmltoimage-cannot-connect-to-x-server

Comment: @Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider does not work